# Timeout period for debugger in Intelij Idea (OC4J)

Tags: intellij-idea, remote-debugging, oc4j

The problem is when debugging an application, the debugger stop after 30 second approx.
How can i configure this time out?

using Intellij Idea 12.0.1 and OC4J 101330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a newer version of idea? Idea had some debugging problems http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97389